# ng-repeat not showing list of JSON array in AngularJS 1.5, but I can see values individually

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using a REST architecture on the backend using CakePHP 3 that returns a JSON Array with this format according to firebug, it's a 200 OK, with this response:

```
    {
    "recipes": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "modificadodsadasdas"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "dasdasdasdasdas"
        }
    ]
}
```

My index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body ng-app="AppRecetas">
  <div ng-controller="RecetasCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
      <li>{{recipe.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/consumidor_rest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my consumidor_rest.js that brings the data from the REST webservice(which is on the same server):

```
var app = angular.module("AppRecetas", []);

app.controller("RecetasCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/services/recipes/index.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.recipes = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

The console of firebug doesn't show any errors and the ajax call is correct with the correct response. But the ng-repeat is just showing one single dot of the ul with no value. If I use inside the ng-repeat:

```
 <li>{{recipe[0].name}}</li>
```

I can see the first element displayed correctly. What's going wrong?. I guess it's a problem with how the array is being delivered by cakePHP, but I'm not sure......

Comment: Try setting `$scope.recipes` to `data.recipes`.

Comment: need to see wat u get in response ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the data object that your are getting from the http call. I think your data object is the JSON object and the "recipes" property inside the object is your array. So consider changing your $scope.recipes = data to 
`$scope.recipes = data.recipes`. 
For verifying the data object in your UI print something like this:

```
{{ $scope.recipes | json }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be that the object aren't turned into propper objects.
You might wanna try to turn them into JSON objects, like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++){
   recipesArray.push(JSON.parse(recipes[i]));
}
$scope.recipes = recipesArray;
```

And then in the view

```
<ul ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
  <li>{{recipe.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your http call returns the data in another object (I suspect response.data, in your case: $scope.recipes = data.data;

Edit: just console.log your return data from the http call.