# Why does ng-repeat return only one object from my MongoDB results?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

In trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337951/nodejs-controller-yeoman-ng-repeat-returns-everything-together-once-only-ret/41338045?noredirect=1#comment69879601_41338045), I decided to break down the problem into something simpler.

**Problem**: If I use ng-repeat to create rows for every element in "test", I instead get one row with one large JSON object.

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-view class="ng-scope">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>JSON for each object</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="X in test">
                <td>{{ X }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Resulting JSON**:

[image: this is a HTML table where there should be more than one row with each object but there is only 1]

**test.js** (clientApp.controller:TestCtrl)

```
'use strict';
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('TestCtrl', function (Test) {
    this.test = Test.getList().$object;
});
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('clientApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'restangular'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, RestangularProvider
  ) {

    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:3000');

    $routeProvider
      .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'TestCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'test'
      })

      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  })
  .factory('TestRestangular', function(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
            id: '_id'
        });
    });
  })
  .factory('Test', function(TestRestangular) {
    return TestRestangular.service('test');
  });
```

**In summary**: There should be more rows, one for every JSON object my test database, but instead I get one large JSON blob.

**Update** @therobinkim suggested that I change the ng-repeat query to "X in learn.learn", which provides the following interesting Restangular JSON stuff:
[image]

Comment: Just to confirm... it the `Resulting JSON` you posted what actually gets received by the controller (perhaps verified via a `console.log`)? Or is it just what you expected to be there (eg, you looked at the database and wrote it out)?

Comment: @therobinkim that was illustrative but I see how it can confuse. I have placed in its place the image I had at the bottom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<tr ng-repeat="X in test.test">...</tr>`

The first `test` is from `controllerAs` in your `$routerProvider` code.

The second `test` is from `this.test` in your `TestCtrl` code.

**UPDATE:** The `$object` in `this.test = Test.getList().$object;` is important to use in this format. Alternatively, you can use Promises. https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#enhanced-promises

Comment: Interesting! That does change things. I get restangular JSON blob code in 4 rows now. I have added that as an update to the question above. If you are suggesting there is a variable name clash, should I rename ''test'' from $routerProvider's **controllerAs.test** and TestCtrl's **this.test**?

Comment: To a human, the variables names look the same, but to the computer, there is no naming conflict, so it's up to you whether you'd like to rename it.

Comment: I am expecting to see 3 to come up.

Comment: Aha! I figured it out thanks to you and @ronchi. I left the ng-repeat inquiry, as you stated, as **test.test**, and if you leave $object at the end of the _this.learn = Test.getList().**$object**;_, AngularJS does its job properly. Thank you. Should I let you put these details in your answer or what's the normal protocol?

Comment: @EamonB Ah great find! I'll edit this answer w/ these details for future reference.

Comment: Wait, let me clarify, I meant that ronchi suggested I leave **$object** out and what happened was that when I put it back, it all worked perfectly. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: @EamonB Ah ok that makes more sense based on the research I did earlier. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

where is your test service? try to remove $object

```js
'use strict';
   angular.module('clientApp')
     .controller('TestCtrl', function (Test) {
        //this.learn = Test.getList().$object;
    this.learn = Test.getList();
 });
```

Comment: Removing $object returns the same blob of JSON.

Comment: ''test'' in test.js refers to the Restangular variable ''test'' returned in the **.factory** part of app.js

Comment: Hi @ronchi, it turns out that $object is very important, I will explain in therobinkin's answer